# Equality testing of variables

Tags: c#, .net

I'm working on a project written in C# and .NET 4.0.

There is a function which compares certain properties of two objects. Both objects are of same type. Consider the following class:

```
class A
{
    public UInt32 Prop1 {get; set;}
    public byte Prop2 {get; set;}
    public string Prop3 {get; set;}
    public int[] Prop4 {get; set;}
}
```

In my comparison function, I'm iterating through each properties using reflection, and getting values of the properties:

```
var value1 = t1.GetType().GetProperty(cp.ToString()).GetValue(t1, null);
var value2 = t2.GetType().GetProperty(cp.ToString()).GetValue(t2, null);
```

where both `t1` and `t2` are of type `A` and `cp` is an `enum` of properties:

```
enum Properties
{ Prop1, Prop2, Prop3, Prop4 }
```

Next I'm doing equality test:

```
if (!value1.Equals(value2))
{
    // Handle differences
}
```

When testing for `Prop4`, which returns an array, `Equals()` always returns false even though the array size and content are same.

What's the easiest way to detect that the return type is enumerable and then perform equality testing for individual elements of the enumerable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Type.IsAssignableFrom()` method:

```
if(typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(t2.GetType()))
{

}
```

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to achieve using your technique, but getting properties values using reflection with additional `enum` seems like poor design decision.

**Update**

If you own the classes code you should just implement [`IEquatable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and compare all the properties there.

```
class A : IEquatable<A>
{
    public UInt32 Prop1 { get; set; }
    public byte Prop2 { get; set; }
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }
    public int[] Prop4 { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(A other)
    {
        return other != null
            && Prop1 == other.Prop1
            && Prop2 == other.Prop2
            && Prop3 == other.Prop3
            && System.Linq.Enumerable.SequenceEqual(Prop4, other.Prop4);
    }
}
```

Comment: I, too, agree with Marcin here about using reflection to get property values, but, then again, not sure what the ultimate goal is.

Comment: I'm also not liking the design, but I couldn't find a better way yet. I've to implement comparison function for two objects of same type. This is not going to be complete all-memberwise comparison. Rather, only a fixed subset of properties need to be compare. For example, A class has 40 properties out of which 25 will be included for equality comparison. That's the requirement. Is there any better way to design this? C# is not my primary language.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: yes.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: your solution gives compile error: Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>' requires 1 type arguments

Comment: @Donotalo You said you owned the classes. Why don't you write your code directly, e.g. implementing `IEquatable<T>` interface? Using reflection when you can achieve the same without it doesn't seem right and will not be as fast as *standard* code.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: Thanks for additional help. I'll look at it later. :)

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: actually, implementing `IEquatable` isn't enough because my function need to return a list of "indications" which properties mismatch. I've created the enum to list the differences, i.e., a list of differences will be returned. is there any better way to do that other than the way i'm doing it? 

`if (!value1.Equals(value2))
{
    diffs.Add(Tuple.Create(cp, value1, value2));
}

return diffs;`